# How to get the current database name from a C function/extention?

Tags: c++, c, postgresql

I'm writing a C function/extension. It's a function that'll be called by a trigger. In it, when a trigger is fired, I need determine the name of the current database.

It's a requirement that using `SPI_prepare()`, `SPI_exec()` isn't allowed in this case, therefore querying `current_database()` won't work.

Some other `SPI_get*` will be ok. Or, accessing to the current database name via `TupleDesc` or `TriggerData` somehow too.

How to do it?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question but I suggest looking at the implementation of the `\conninfo` "meta-command" in psql.

Comment: @zwol whatever it is, it'd have to be called using SPI_exec from C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me which of postgresql's server-internal programming interfaces are usable in SPI extensions.  However, the [implementation of the `current_database` SQL function](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/backend_2utils_2adt_2misc_8c.html#a9720c64431ddd8ee1feac75e65f6092c) does this:

> ```
> Name db;
> db = (Name) palloc(NAMEDATALEN);
> namestrcpy(db, get_database_name(MyDatabaseId));
> PG_RETURN_NAME(db);
> ```

So, I think `get_database_name(MyDatabaseId)` is the incantation you want.  It returns a C string, which your C extension can use directly -- the rest of the above is to box up the string in a `Datum` object so the query evaluator can work with it.

Comment: I don't need original implemetation. I need a way to do that inside a trigger. But in it I may not have access to all those functions and variables

Comment: That's what I meant by "it's not clear to me which of postgresql's server-internal interfaces are usable in SPI extensions."  _If_ you have access to `get_database_name` and `MyDatabaseId`, then this is how you do it.  Otherwise I can't help you.

Answer (score -2):

I figured out that a function called "current_database()" seems useful which seems similar to "select database()". Later returns a string which represents the name of the database.
Yes, a parameter that your extension will get in order to deduce context or so.

PL/SQL can create functions. These can in turn call C-Language extensions via shared libraries. Finally, the name can be delegated from database towards extension.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION add_one(integer) RETURNS integer
         AS 'DIRECTORY/funcs', 'add_one'
         LANGUAGE C STRICT;